# Upload Photos to IIS via HTTP-Post multipart-data

Tags: android, iis, upload, webdav

I am running an IIS-Webserver 10 on a Windows Server 2016 machine.
I want to upload photos from my android application via OKHTTP (multipart-data).

Trying that, I always receive the message  "405 - Method  not allowed". 
Enabled WebDav but get the same error.

How can I do that properly?

Here is my code to upload data

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        File file = new File(fullFilepath);

        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

        Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
        builder.url(dmzServer + "Uploads/");

        MultipartBody.Builder bodyBuilder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
        bodyBuilder.addFormDataPart("test.jpeg", file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), file));
        MultipartBody body = bodyBuilder.build();

        final RequestBody requestBody = ProgressHelper.withProgress(body, new ProgressUIListener() {
            @Override
            public void onUIProgressChanged(long numBytes, long totalBytes, float percent, float speed) {
                publishProgress(percent);
            }
        });

        builder.put(requestBody);


        Call call = httpClient.newCall(builder.build());
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.e("CALL", e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                Log.i("CALL", "response");
            }
        });

        return null;
    }
```

Thomas

Comment: add some code for how to send multipart-data

Comment: ok, i did that .

Comment: maybe this error is backend api The 405 error could be caused by PUT method and webdav module. recommend you use the failed request tracing to capture the error log of api for more details.

Comment: thats not the problem